# Zabbix - Filter log based on contents

Tags: windows, events, zabbix, event-log

I am trying to filter on the Event Log ID 4624, for events that only contain the string "Elevated Token: No"

I have tried a 'Matches Regular Expression' of `(?i)Elevated Token: No` but I cannot get the filter to work

How can I set up a pre-processing, where I can get the `Logon Type` number only when `Elevated Token` is `No`?